# Vue Project not working after ubuntu customization

Tags: vue.js, ubuntu

I have created a project using vue.js at the frontend and flask at the backend, It was working perfectly. But, after I customized my ubuntu OS, suddenly I am unable to run the project, my flask and every other framework and library was uninstalled and I am unable to reinstall vue and I get this error message when I try to install vue again:
[image]

Can someone tell me how to resolve this issue?
By Customization, I installed some extensions and then some wallpapers, icon packs etc..

Comment: You’re trying to install a global package without having permissions to do so. That’s to be expected and no “customization” has affected this in any way. If you want to install it globally either do it as root, or give yourself permissions to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a user has mentioned in the replies earlier, what you are trying to do is installing a global package, and the error displayed there clearly stated that you lacked permissions, and the customizations you mentioned should not have any impact on this.

Since you are using Ubuntu, just add a `sudo` in front of the command that you are trying to execute and it should be fixed.